# Nutch path error

Tags: nutch

following this tutorial http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial
and http://www.nutchinstall.blogspot.com/

when i take the command

```
bin/nutch crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 3 -topN 5
```

i have this error

```
LinkDb: adding segment: file:/C:/cygwin/home/LeHung/apache-nutch-1.4-bin/runtime/local/crawl/segments/20120301233259
LinkDb: adding segment: file:/C:/cygwin/home/LeHung/apache-nutch-1.4-bin/runtime/local/crawl/segments/20120301233337
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/C:/cygwin/home/LeHung/apache-nutch-1.4-bin/runtime/local/crawl/segments/20120301221729/parse_data
Input path does not exist: file:/C:/cygwin/home/LeHung/apache-nutch-1.4-bin/runtime/local/crawl/segments/20120301221754/parse_data
Input path does not exist: file:/C:/cygwin/home/LeHung/apache-nutch-1.4-bin/runtime/local/crawl/segments/20120301221804/parse_data
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:190)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat.listStatus(SequenceFileInputFormat.java:44)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:201)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeOldSplits(JobClient.java:810)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:781)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:730)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1249)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.LinkDb.invert(LinkDb.java:175)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.LinkDb.invert(LinkDb.java:149)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl.run(Crawl.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl.main(Crawl.java:55)
```

i using cygwin, windows to run nutch

Comment: Looks like there are some directories within segments without the required parse_data subfolder. Have you run the crawl before and then deleted some directories there?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have **parse_data** folder present as per the path given above in the error. Make sure that the **folders inside the crawl** folder that you have given in the command are created and available to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem.
I deleted the db and directories . After that, it ran ok.

Comment: It seems work for me. But if i have crawled for days, that will not be so good.